# find $y= \lim_\limits{t\to\infty} \left({{t-3}\over {2t+1}}\right)^t$

Tags: calculus, limits

> find $y= \lim_\limits{t\to\infty} \left({{t-3}\over {2t+1}}\right)^t$

My attempt:
$$\ln y= \ln{\left({{t-3}\over {2t+1}}\right)^t}$$

$$\lim_\limits{t\to\infty} \ln{y} = \lim_\limits{t\to\infty} t(\ln{(t-3)}- \ln{(2t+1)})$$

True? and how can I complete?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Compute this way:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}t\cdot\ln \left(\frac{t-3}{2t+1}\right)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{t-3}{2t+1}\right)}{\frac1t}.$$

Here the numerator tends to $\ln\frac12<0$ and the denominator tends to zero through positive numbers. So the limit is $-\infty$.

Comment: I'd support this way of proving the limit, since some of the other procedures imply taking the limit by parts which is not necessarily correct. I'll just add that the limit must be $-\infty$, since $ln(\frac{1}{2}) <0$

Comment: You should be concluding that $\ln(y) = -\infty$ and hence $y = 0$. The way it's worded, it might look like you're saying the original limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: @AOrtiz: thanks.

Comment: @NotAMathematician: thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is zero. To see this, note that
$$
\frac{t-3}{2t+1} = \frac{1-3/t}{2+1/t}
$$
converges to $1/2,$ and thus is less than $2/3$ in absolute value for $t\ge t_0,$ for some $t_0>0.$ But
$$
\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^t
$$
converges to 0.

Comment: That is a very dangerous way to show student how to compute a limit . That failed in many cases . the famous one is the Euler Constant – Guy Fson

Answer (score 1):

It is :

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\bigg(\frac{t-3}{2t+1}\bigg)=\frac{1}{2}$$

and :

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^t=0$$

hence :

$$y= \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \left({{t-3}\over {2t+1}}\right)^t=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\ln(y)$ can be rewritten as
$$
\ln(y) = \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\ln\Big(\frac{t-3}{2t+1}\Big)}{1/t}.
$$
However, by continuity of ln, the numerator tends to $\ln(1/2) = -\ln(2)$ as $t\to\infty$ and the denominator tends to $0$ as $t\to\infty$. Hence $\ln(y) = -\infty$. Now deduce that $y = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that $\frac{t-3}{2t+1}\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: And what?${}{}{}$

Comment: And $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^t\rightarrow0$.

Comment: That is a very dangerous way to show student how to compute a limit . That failed in many cases . the famous one is the Euler Constant

Comment: @Guy Fsone In our case it's obvious: $0\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^7}}=0.$

Comment: I don't have any problem but just worry about learners.  I don't understand that relation at the end

Answer (score 0):

$$
y= \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \left({{t-3}\over {2t+1}}\right)^t \\
= \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac12 \cdot {{t-3}\over {t+0.5}}\right)^t \\
= \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac12 \cdot (1 - {{3.5}\over {t+0.5}})\right)^t 
$$

Let $(t+0.5)/3.5 = x$ then we have

$$
y= \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac12 \cdot (1 - \frac1x)\right)^{3.5 x - 0.5}
$$
Now use that for large x, $(1-1/x)^x \to e^{-1}$, so we have 
$$
y= \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac12 \cdot e^{-1/x}\right)^{3.5 x - 0.5} \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}  \left(\frac12 \right)^{3.5 x - 0.5} \cdot \left(e^{-3.5 +0.5/x}\right)  \\
= e^{-3.5} \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}  \left(\frac12 \right)^{3.5 x - 0.5} = 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Set $h=1/t$

$$y= \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \left({{t-3}\over {2t+1}}\right)^t =\lim_{h\rightarrow0^+ } \left({{1-3h}\over {2+h}}\right)^{1/h} \\= \lim_{h\rightarrow0 } \left({{1-3h}\over {2+h}}\right)^{1/h} \\=\lim_{h\rightarrow0^+ }\exp\left(3\frac{\ln(1-3h)}{3h} -\frac{\ln(h +2)}{h}\right)  = 0$$

Since $$ \lim_{h\rightarrow0 } -\frac{\ln(h +2)}{h} =-\infty$$
and $$ \lim_{h\rightarrow0 } \frac{\ln(1-3h)}{-3h} = 1$$